# The Gamma function and factorial satisfy $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$

Tags: proof-verification, gamma-function

This was a question from a mock paper, for my upcoming exam however my teacher unhelpfully did not post any solutions.

> Prove that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$.

[image]

Can anyone check if my proof is correct.

Thank you for reading.

-Alexis

Comment: It seems you forgot to show $\Gamma(1)=1$.

Comment: And, in the spirit of the passages you are writing, "$\left[f(x) + \int_0^\infty g(x) \,dx\right]_0^\infty$" should more correctly be "$\left[f(x) + \int_0^x g(t) \,dt\right]_0^\infty$".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen wow that was quick, In that case: gamma(n)=(n-1)! ergo gamma(1) = (1-1)!=0!=1

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you for your post, the reason I wrote wrt to t in the 1st line, is because I try and commit this formula to memory, and then adjust it where the question requires i.e. if it was t+1 instead of n+1 in the question. Thank you for your help. Is the upper limit x in the integral? In my work in this area it has always been to infinity, whilst you are probably right, would you please elaborate on this if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that he property $$G(n + 1) = n G(n)$$ you establish also holds for any constant multiple of $\Gamma$, including the zero function.

Since the proof you give is basically an inductive argument (it might be useful to say a little more in your solution about how this goes), it suffices to add a base case, that is, show that the identity holds for the lowest applicable value of $n$. Since $0!$ makes sense (but $(-1)!$ is not defined), one should show that $\Gamma(0 + 1) = 0!$.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement this into my answers in future. And thanks for your edit too.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

**You can make it short:**

From the definition of $\Gamma$, we have

$$\Gamma(1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx=1.$$

Then by parts, integrating $e^{-x}$,

$$\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^\infty x^{n}e^{-x}\,dx=-\left.x^ne^{-x}\right|_0^\infty+n\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,dx=n\Gamma(n)$$

because $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^ne^{-x}=0$. The integral converges for all positive integer $n$.

This shows that $\Gamma(n+1)$ and $n!$ follow the same recurrence and are equal for all $n$.

---

The crux of the proof is the integration by parts, which reduces the exponent of $x$ and induces the recurrence relation.

---

**A direct proof:**

From $(P(x)e^{-x})'=(P'(x)-P(x))e^{-x}$, you see that you can find the antiderivative of $x^ne^{-x}$ by solving

$$P'(x)-P(x)=x^n.$$

Expanding the polynomial, this is

$$-p_nx^n+(np_n-p_{n-1})x^{n-1}+((n-1)p_{n-1}-p_{n-2})x^{n-2}+\cdots p_1-p_0=x^n$$

and by identification,

$$p_k=-\frac{n!}{k!}.$$

Hence

$$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=-n!\left.\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\cdots1\right)e^{-x}\right|_0^\infty=n!$$ as only the last term contributes.

Answer (score -4):

If  $~n~$ is a positive integer$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$ For negative integers it's undefined.

So that.                              $$\Gamma(n+1)= n \Gamma(n)$$
            $$=n \Gamma(n-1+1)=n (n-1)\Gamma(n-1) $$
           $$ =n(n-1)\Gamma(n-2+1)   $$
          $$  =n(n-1)(n-2)\Gamma(n-2)   $$
         $$  =.......   ....   ..... $$
         $$   =n(n-1)(n-2)....3.2.1.\Gamma(1)$$
         $$   =n(n-1)(n-2)..... 3.2.1. $$
        $$    = n!   $$ since $\Gamma(1)=1$,

It's simple proof

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: This doesn't prove anything.